# Intermediate level student or intermediate-level student?

Tags: hyphenation, compounds, compound-adjectives

*Intermediate level student* or *intermediate-level student*? Which one is more correct/preferable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I much prefer  "intermediate-level student"

Explanation

When reading this sort of expression in English we tend to assign attributes in reverse order, e.g.

*A big stone wall.*  This is not a wall made of big stones, it is a big wall made of indeterminately sized stones.  We automatically put "stone" with "wall" to make "stone-wall".

In the case of 'intermediate level student' this looks structurally like 'intermediate physics student', in other words a physics student who is intermediate, i.e. an intermediate physics-student.

Because your phrase goes against this general rule, it becomes easier to read with the hyphen. We are talking about an 'intermediate-level student' rather than an 'intermediate level-student. (someone who studies levels).

I hope that makes sense!